# How to filter out null values in count() in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe with null values in its column.

when i am using count() on a particular column, it does return me the count of all the unique values but it also returns the count of null values.

Code:

`df.groupBy('version').count().orderBy('count', ascending=False).show()`

Output:

| version | count |
| --- | --- |
| null | 2734247 |
| 4.2.0 | 1663406 |
| 4.1.2 | 389947 |
| 41.13 | 302074 |

i want to filter out the null value and its count in the output. how do i do it?

this is the expected output i need:

| version | count |
| --- | --- |
| 4.2.0 | 1663406 |
| 4.1.2 | 389947 |
| 4.1.3 | 302074 |

I mostly used pandas and it returns output with the count of null values but its not the same with pyspark and i am new to pyspark.

also i want to replace the null values with the value with highest count, so i need to also replace null values with 4.2.0

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `df.filter('version is not null')...`

Comment: how can i use filter with groupby,count and the rest of my code?

Comment: simply by chaining: `df.filter('version is not null').groupBy('version').count().orderBy('count', ascending=False).show()`

Comment: thanks it works. Is there any way to put the value with most counts in a variable?

Comment: version_with_most_counts = df.filter('version is not null').groupBy('version').count().orderBy('count', ascending=False).collect()[0].version